# pydev: debug in console mode (interactive)?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm just starting to use pydev but am fairly experienced with Eclipse.

I can use F11 to debug a file.

I can use Ctrl-Alt-Enter to start a console after running the current file, but it does not seem to respect breakpoints.

Is there a way to start a console (similar to Ctrl-Alt-Enter) in debug mode?

Comment: Would this be more appropriate for Superuser?

Comment: I'd say no for use help on programming tools, as the audience is focused on programming here.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to have a console in debug mode: start the debug, when reaching your first breakpoint (maybe you will want to add a breakpoint in line 1) the console in the debug perspective is in fact interactive.

Though the console is kind of laggy but it works, more info can be found at : http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this (got pulled off python work for a while), and unfortunately it doesn't work. Yes, the debugger works in non-interactive mode. And yes, if you are stopped at a breakpoint in debugging, your console is in interactive mode. But when you run things in this interactive mode, python doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is now available in PyDev. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065948/110451 for details.