# PyDev: How to invoke debugging specific command from console (with breakpoints)?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pydev

Suppose I wrote a function, which I want to debug.

PyDev helps debugging a lot with its advanced features, like breakpoints.

After setting the breakpoints, one way of debugging is to write an invocation of the function in `def main()` or just in the body of the module, and to press the [image] button.

Is it possible to launch a debug session of the function together with its arguments from the console? (Just like in RStudio or VBA...)

---

This question is a duplicate of [pydev: debug in console mode (interactive)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359157/pydev-debug-in-console-mode-interactive)

---

Update:
I really don't know, what is the magic combination of clicks, that make the interactive debugging possible.

Here is what I do, which is *not working* (on Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse 4.4.I20140606-1215 with PyDev 3.6.0.2014062323, Python 3.4.0, IPython 1.2.1)

## First try:

First, I create a new PyDev Project: [image]

Then I insert a new .py file with some code on, and create some breakpoints: 
[image]

Then I right click somewhere on the code, `Debug As...`->`Python run`.

And then 2 consoles open, none of them is IPython. The active console is named `[Debug console] proba.py`. [image: [Debug console] proba.py]  Typing commands into this console doesn't make the computer to execute them.

There is other console available, named just `proba.py`.[image: <code>proba.py</code> console] This console is fully interactive, although *it is not IPython*.

This is indeed an interactive debugger. One can step through the code and inspect variables. Unfortunately updating the variables is not supported; if I enter a command `a=10` the variable doesn't get updated.

## Second try

This time, before launching the debug session let's try starting IPython. After Ctrl+Alt+Enter I choose `Console for currently active editor`:

[image]

Then Python3 (because this is what I need):
[image]

After that I have a fully working IPython console. [image: IPython console]

When I execute the file via `execfile`, it triggers an error `Failed to create input stream: Read timed out`: [image]

Although it seems, that stepping through the code works, I cannot access the variables from the IPython console, although it is possible to access them from Variables view:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes, you can do that in the latest PyDev versions.

You have to enable that in the preferences as explained in:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#full-debug-support-in-interactive-console

(i.e.: Connect console to a debug session)

---

Edit (related to 2nd part):

Unfortunately, the way things are, this is expected... your code is 'blocked' in a breakpoint and thus the console can't answer to you nor do any evaluation while you're in the breakpoint in this mode (you can only use the debugger watches/expressions at this point), so, the idea is that you use the console to execute things and then if you want you can add a breakpoint, but you can only use the console again when you left the breakpoint.

Note that if you want to use the interactive console in the context of a breakpoint, a different approach would be selecting a stack frame (in the debug view) > right-clicking it > pydev > Debug Console (or you can also in the debug view create a new console view connected to the debug session for the same effect).