# PyDev: What is the difference between "Console" and "Interactive Console"?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ipython, pydev

I am trying to prove a claim, that it is possible to connect debugging session to existing IPython console ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018869/pydev-is-it-possible-to-invoke-debugging-specific-command-from-console-with-br/25065948#25065948), [[2]](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#full-debug-support-in-interactive-console)). Maybe I don't get the terminology right.

What is the difference between "Console" and "Interactive Console"?

[image]

vs

[image]

Interesting fact is that the "Interactive Console" is always disabled (i.e. non-interactive) in contrast to a "Console", which behaves as expected, i.e. as IPython console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyDev interactive console is actually in the 'Console' view (but it has a special one which you can create which is the 'interactive console' -- in the Console View you can choose to create one bound to a debug session -- if a breakpoint is currently active, just choose the create new action in the console view and choose 'PyDev console' with a breakpoint active).

The 'Interactive Console' view is from some other plugin (not sure which one as it doesn't appear for me).