# Enter pydev interactive console immediately on F11?

Tags: eclipse, config, pydev

I would like to <kbd>F11</kbd> a python file in Eclipse and when I hit a breakpoint automatically enter the Python Interactive Console (not the default pydev debug console).

I understand that I could upon entering debug mode open a new interactive python console (I have turned on the connection between the interactive console and the debug console) and work from there. But not only is that an extra step but it is frustrating because everytime I interact with such an interactive console it shoves me back to the debug console! Then I have to go review the interactive console. I also understand that I could do a 'runfile' from within the interactive console, but I really want to use the convenient <kbd>F11</kbd> capacity of eclipse to just be in an editor, hit <kbd>F11</kbd> and when I break enter the interactive console.

Basically I would like the Interactive Console to be my debug console. Possible?

If the <kbd>F11</kbd> approach is not possible, is there another approach? My goal is to get my history of command typing available to me with arrow keys. Not possible in the default python debug console from what I can tell. Perhaps if I made the pydev debug console ipython?

Thanks, I have searched a lot on this but can't come up with a solution.

Comment: So far I'm fairly convinced, that there is no better solution. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018869/pydev-how-to-invoke-debugging-specific-command-from-console-with-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

from PyDev 3.9.2 onwards, a console prompt with history, code-completion, etc. will appear automatically.

See: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2015/02/pydev-392-released.html for details.